# Image blurry before hover state and after transform scale

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am having an odd issue when I try and use a zoom (transform: scale) property on an image on hover state. For some reason, the image appears blurry before and after the scale transition, but during the transition it is sharp. Any CSS tricks to overcome the blurry image is appreciated!

Yes, I have tried many of the various methods already posted elsewhere on the forum.

Link to the example is seen here.
https://woodmart.xtemos.com/home-cars/demo/cars/

And a link to a video displaying the problem is here.
https://app.usebubbles.com/hEg29xH6DL5HLF17V5mudp/comments-on-woodmart-xtemos-com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `transform: scale(1.5);` instead of using `transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);` I think that property `scale3d` is making your image blurry.

Comment: I have tried this. It gives the same result.
https://app.usebubbles.com/azYGdr3DqZr6fd8iD9EGYL/comments-on-woodmart-xtemos-com/

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the images in the link example you provided, but my guess would be that it's related to either the file format or sub-pixel division error.

Do the images have a decimal point in the width/height?

Can you try adding a very small number to their resting position between transitions? (for example instead of transition from 1 to 1.5 try 1.001 to 1.5001)

Comment: I have tried various images and they all do the same thing. I have tried lossless cropping (exact x/y coordinates in 8/16px). Images are exact dimensions. I have tried as you suggested and it did not work.

Comment: To see the images in the link provided just scroll down below the main hero image.